# Logging ELMAH errors to Elasticsearch

Tags: .net, wcf, elasticsearch, elmah

How do I add a target to send logs to my Elasticsearch server? Ideally I would like to have two **errorLog** in my WCF application, where one is sending data to SQL and another one to Elasticsearch. This is a temporary solution until we switch off the SQL endpoint.

This is what I currently have:

web.config

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ErrorLog"/>
    <errorLog type="My.Namespace.ElasticsearchErrorLog, My.Namespace" indexName="Elmah" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false"/>
</elmah>
```

ElasticsearchErrorLog.cs

```
public class ElasticsearchErrorLog : Elmah.ErrorLog
{
    public ElasticsearchErrorLog(IDictionary config)
    {
    }

    public override ErrorLogEntry GetError(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetErrors(int pageIndex, int pageSize, IList errorEntryList)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string Log(Error error)
    {
        Logger.ElmahInstance.Error(error.Exception, "Something went wrong {Message} ...", error.Message);

        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ELMAH doesn't support writing to multiple error logs using `web.config`. With that said, there's a small hack that allows you to do it. I'm using it here to log to both SQL Server and [elmah.io](https://elmah.io/), but the approach would be similar in your case:

[Logging to multiple ELMAH logs](https://docs.elmah.io/logging-to-multiple-elmah-logs/)

In your case, you could log to Elasticsearch manually inside the `ErrorLog_Logged` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Nlog to store your logs to elasticsearch. Please find the below link for your reference.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch/
```

Let me know if you still facing any issues.